# Inject the value of xml id into spring bean

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm curious if anyone knows a quick way to accomplish my goal.
I want to inject the value of the id into a String on my spring bean.

This is what I want in a nutshell:

```
<bean id="matsientst" class="com.matt.Matt"/>
```

---

```
public class Matt {
    @Value("#id")
    String id;
}
```

The reason I need this is that we have a lot of objects that are configured in our spring xml that I also need to manage in the DB. The Spring id is a convenient key that I can use. I don't want to have to inject all my objects since I have them all abstracted I could elegantly have the Abstract class set the ID. That is, if this works.
Thanks
-matt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just implement `BeanNameAware`, and Spring will supply the `id` or `name` attribute (whichever one you used), e.g.

```
public class Matt implements BeanNameAware {
    private String id;

    public void setName(String beanName) {
       this.id = beanName;
    }
}
```

Comment: but won't that clutter my code with unnecessary dependence on the Spring API? if there was some option to do it with Spring EL, or something else that resides entirely in the XML config file, my code would stay blissfully unaware of anything starting with "org.springframework"

Comment: `#{#this.name}` could work, but I haven't tested it yet.